# jquery twitter plugin that is seo friendly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter

ive been googling and failed to find a jquery twitter plugin that is seo friendly. by seo friendly, i mean one that initially loads the data in html, then later by ajax. most plugins load by ajax so are not seo friendly, i need google to be able to index the tweets

Comment: SEO obsession detected! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible to do with *just* JS - if the initial page has to have the HTML on it then the server side language has to put it there. What you want is a *PHP Library*, **not** a jQuery plugin...

Since no sane jQuery plugin makes any assumptions about the server-side technologies, you will just have to get the jQuery plugin to overwrite the div in which you put the output of your PHP twitter feed library.

Comment: hmm... yup. any php library you know of? for outputing tweets?

Comment: no, just commenting on the impossibility of what you were initially asking for... i've never had to interface with twitter in any language, but now you know what you are looking for ;)